# Find a large number of distinct field values in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb

I want to find all distinct values for a given field in a collection. The [distinct()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) operation seems to max out at 16 MB, which is very low. I want to store these distinct values in a collection for later, or be able to `limit()` to page over them.

The number of items will be about 50 million, around 5 gigabytes.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [map-reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/).

Comment: It does sound like it, yes. But does that mean I have to build up a multi-gigabyte JS object in the reduce function?

Comment: As an alternative you could do something like this `db.bar.find({}, {field_of_interest: 1, _id: 0}).forEach(function(doc) { db.foo.insert(doc); });
db.foo.ensureIndex({field_of_interest: 1}, { unique: true, dropDups: true });` or run map-reduce using [Hadoop connector](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/hadoop/)

Comment: Thanks @zero323 that's one thing I could consider doing, certainly. The field is already indexed in the original table though, so I would have thought there would be a cleaner way.

Comment: If field is indexed you can always sort by that field and yield only changing values although If you have sharded collection m-r would a much better solution. Depending on you know about values distribution you could also try combining multiple `count` operation on range based bins.

Comment: Yield changing values when? In a reduce function? Do I know that the iteration happens in order? The documentation seems to suggest that I can't rely on iteration order. And I'd still have to store the values in a JS object wouldn't I? Or are you talking about running a cursor over the ordered collection in a client and then re-inserting based on that?

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem.

`distinct()` will go over the 16MB document limit. Therefore the only option left is to use a `map-reduce`, but that does not take advantage if the field is already indexed.

```
mf=function() { emit ( this.field_of_interest , {} ); };
rf=function(key, emits) { return {}  };
db.YourCollection.mapReduce( mf, rf, { out: {replace: "UniqueValues" } } );
```